# How do I close Kendo UI modal popup from Ajax.BeginForm onSuccess event?

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc-3, jquery, kendo-asp.net-mvc

I am using Kendo UI with asp.net MVC 3 design pattern.  I have a page that uses a modal panel and the content is loading from a .cshtml page that has an `Ajax.BeginForm` contained within it.

Here is my dilemma: I would like to close the window when the `onSuccess` event is fired on the ajax form.  What would I have to do since this would not be a button click?  Here is the code I found for the case of a button click:

```
$( buttonInsideWindow ).closest(".k-window-content").data("kendoWindow").close()
```

I am not sure what code I need to use from `onSuccess` event.

Answer (score 2):

It is fairly simple.

In you `onSuccess` event handler, you can use the Id of your model window to close it

```
$("#windowId").data("kendoWindow").close();
```